# Partitions not showing while installing Ubuntu on SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd, usb-installation

I installed a new SSD in my HP Elitebook 820. While installing Ubuntu on that SSD, there are no partitions on it, and everything is greyed out
Also, I have only a new SSD, the previous one is not in the laptop now.